# Style not showing when scrolling

Tags: html, scroll

I am having a problem when I have a scrolling div when I scroll the background and border styles are not applied to the inner divs.

I have tried to simplify the problem here;

https://jsfiddle.net/w498trmf/22/

```css
.GridScrollOuter {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.GridScrollHeader {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.GridHeader {
  background-color: #c8ffbb !Important;
  color: red;
  border-top: 1px solid #337ab7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #337ab7;
}

.Column {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="GridScrollOuter">
  <div class="GridScrollHeader">
    <div class="GridHeader">
      <div class="Column">
        <button>Button1</button>
      </div>
      <div class="Column">
        <button>Button2</button>
      </div>
      <div class="Column">
        <button>Button3</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Apply the styles to `.GridScrollHeader` - like the commented out styles in your jsfiddle.

Comment: Yes I could do this but as the .GridScrollHeader will contain other elements I do not want to apply the style at this level. I really want to apply the style at the .GridHeader level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have

```
.Column {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Three `div`s with 50% width, so it's like 150% width. And `.GridHeader` is only `100% width`.

Try this:
Make your `.GridHeader` 150% width

```
.GridHeader {
  background-color: #c8ffbb !Important;
  color: red;
  border-top: 1px solid #337ab7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #337ab7;
  width: 150%;
}
```

and your `.Column` 33% width:

```
.Column {
  width: 33%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**Or** if you will always have different number of `div`s, then forget about `width` and just add these classes to `.GridHeader`:

```
.GridHeader {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

**Here's the code snippet for non-constant number of inner divs.**

```css
.GridScrollOuter {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.GridScrollHeader {
  /*background-color: #c8ffbb !Important;
  border-top: 1px solid #337ab7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #337ab7;*/
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.GridHeader {
  background-color: #c8ffbb !Important;
  color: red;
  border-top: 1px solid #337ab7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #337ab7;
  width: 150%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="GridScrollOuter">
  <div class="GridScrollHeader">
    <div class="GridHeader">
      <div class="Column">
        <button>Button1</button>
      </div>
      <div class="Column">
        <button>Button2</button>
      </div>
      <div class="Column">
        <button>Button3</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This method falls down entirely when there is an unknown number of `Column`'s

Comment: @Turnip, I've updated my answer to work with any number of `div`s.

Comment: That still doesn't work correctly. Your `.Columns` have collapsed to the width of the button and they aren't spaced in the same way as OPs current code. The last is aligned to the right.

Comment: shshame that has given me enough to get it working. I have applied your styles and then dynamically working out the width of .GridHeader depending upon how many 'columns' are shown. This appears to work. Thanks for your help.